# How to set http_x_forwarded_for to remote_addr

Tags: php, apache

I have 2 hosting that give me different information about IP and Proxy ,
e.g , My IP : 111.22.33.44 and My Proxy : 123.45.67.89

in hostinger.com

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = 123.45.67.89
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = 111.22.33.44
```

but

in hawkhost.com

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = 111.22.33.44
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = 123.45.67.89
```

Do you know, why is this different?
Thank You...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REMOTE_ADDR` is the IP address from which the connection is comming from. It's usually the real user's IP, but it can also be the IP of a Proxy or VPN the user may be using to hide his identity. There is no way to know.

`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is the value of a HTTP header sent by the connecting peer. It's usually set by a Proxy Server that is tunneling the traffic and discloses the real IP of the Proxy user. But bewere, it does not deserve trust because it can be easily spoofed.